# DatePicker not selecting the correct date

Tags: objective-c, ios, date, datepicker

I have a `Button` in my `view`.On tapping the `Button` you get a `datepicker` which defaults to today's date, the user can then select the date they want to search for events.
The problem is, no matter what date I select, it always returns the current day and adds this to my `TextField` which i have placed inside mu `Button`.Can any one tell me where I am wrong.am setting the date picker programatically.

Below is my code hopefully someone can help me out!

//displaying date picker while clicking on button

```
 - (IBAction)startDateButtonAction:(id)sender
  {
     if ([popOverController isPopoverVisible]) {
    [popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
  }
    UIViewController* popoverContent = [[UIViewController alloc] init]; //ViewController
    UIView *popoverView1 = [[UIView alloc] init];   //view
    datePicker          =[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];//Date picker
    datePicker.frame    =CGRectMake(0,0,240, 150);
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [datePicker setMaximumDate:[[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:24*60*60*-6]];
    [datePicker setMinimumDate:[DateFormatter getSubtractedDateForomCurrentDateWith:35]];
    datePicker.date     = [DateFormatter getDateFromString:startDateLabel.text];
    datePicker.selected = YES;
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(datePickerValue)       forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [popoverView1 addSubview:datePicker];
    popoverContent.view = popoverView1;
    popOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]    initWithContentViewController:popoverContent];
    [popOverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(240, 150) animated:NO];
    [popOverController presentPopoverFromRect:startDateButton.frame inView:headerView   permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
```

//action function while selecting any of the date from date picker

```
 - (void) datePickerValue
  {
     NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
     [offsetComponents setDay:-6]; 
     NSDate *labelStartDate = datePicker.date;
     startDate = [DateFormatter getOnlyDateComponentsFromDate:labelStartDate];
     NSDate *labelEndDate = [self addDayToDate:startDate Number:6];
     startDateLabel.text = [DateFormatter getDateStringddmmyyy:labelStartDate];
     endDateLabel.text   = [DateFormatter getDateStringddmmyyy:labelEndDate];
   }
```

[including the functions that am used here]

```
//used for getting date components
+(NSDate *) getOnlyDateComponentsFromDate:(NSDate *)date
{
unsigned int flags = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSCalendar* calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:flags fromDate:date];
NSDate* dateOnly = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
return dateOnly;
}  


 - (NSDate *) addDayToDate:(NSDate *)date Number:(int) number
{
  NSDate *newDate = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*number];
  return newDate;
}
```

Iam using ARC.
here `datePicker.date` gives me only the current date even though I select any other dates

Comment: are you adding the datePicker in IB? If so, are you sure the IBOutlet is linked correctly?

Comment: No iam adding date picker programatically

Comment: are you sure its the `datePicker.date` value directly no the `[DateFormatter getDateStringddmmyyy:labelStartDate]` ?

Comment: @SumiSadiq : please show the code where you creating the date picker.

Comment: For items that are instance variables (`DateFormatter`?, `startDate`, etc.), please provide the relevant code from your .h that shows how they are defined (what class, `strong`/`weak`; `retain`/`assign`). Is `DateFormatter` a class or an instance variable. Are you using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)? What do the `getOnlyDateComponentsFromDate:`, `getDateStringddmmyyy:`, and `[self addDayToDate:Number:]` methods do (provide their code as well).

Comment: i have included code where am creating the date picker

Comment: Thanks for all for your valuable reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out my mistake at last..The problem was with my code where i set the maximum and minimum value for the datePicker.removing the code for setting maximum and minimum value the code works fine..

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise your datepicker like this.

```
 _datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
_datePicker.tag=1951;
_datePicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDate;

[_datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(ageChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[_actionSheet addSubview:_datePicker];
```

And for your this method: `ageChanged:`

-(void)ageChanged:(id)sender {

```
NSDate *datePicked = [_datePicker date];
NSLog(@"%@", datePicked);
formattedDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicked];
```

}

and set `dateFormatter` as per your requirement. 
while changing your date it will give you the date you have selected in date Picker.

I hope this will help you for date picker.